# How to save Facebook user data to MySql database with Angular and Ionic

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

I am working an an Ionic app where I implement native Facebook login (followed this tutorial -> https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework). As you can see the Facebook data now gets stored in local storage. I need to save this data in my MySql database.

I got this to work without any issues. Now I want to store the Facebook user data to my MySql database.

Basically I am not sure where to place my http request to pass the data along to my database or how to even do it code wise.

I should mention that I have a backend already setup (which is coded with bootstrap, html, css, js php and mysql).

So the url for my users would be this: http://www.xxxxx.com/user.php

Part of my controller code:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $q, UserService, $ionicLoading) {
  // This is the success callback from the login method
  var fbLoginSuccess = function(response) {
    if (!response.authResponse){
      fbLoginError("Cannot find the authResponse");
      return;
    }

    var authResponse = response.authResponse;

    getFacebookProfileInfo(authResponse)
    .then(function(profileInfo) {
      // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
      UserService.setUser({
        authResponse: authResponse,
                userID: profileInfo.id,
                name: profileInfo.name,
                email: profileInfo.email,
        picture : "http://graph.facebook.com/" + authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
      });
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $state.go('app.dashboard');
    }, function(fail){
      // Fail get profile info
      console.log('profile info fail', fail);
    });
  };

  // This is the fail callback from the login method
  var fbLoginError = function(error){
    console.log('fbLoginError', error);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  };

  // This method is to get the user profile info from the facebook api
  var getFacebookProfileInfo = function (authResponse) {
    var info = $q.defer();

    facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=email,name&access_token=' + authResponse.accessToken, null,
      function (response) {
                console.log('logging facebook response',response);
        info.resolve(response);
      },
      function (response) {
                console.log(response);
        info.reject(response);
      }
    );
    return info.promise;
  };

  //This method is executed when the user press the "Login with facebook" button
  $scope.facebookSignIn = function() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(success){
      if(success.status === 'connected'){
        // The user is logged in and has authenticated your app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed request, and the time the access token
        // and signed request each expire
        console.log('getLoginStatus', success.status);

            // Check if we have our user saved
            var user = UserService.getUser('facebook');

            if(!user.userID){
                    getFacebookProfileInfo(success.authResponse)
                    .then(function(profileInfo) {
                        // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
                        UserService.setUser({
                            authResponse: success.authResponse,
                            userID: profileInfo.id,
                            name: profileInfo.name,
                            email: profileInfo.email,
                            picture : "http://graph.facebook.com/" + success.authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
                        });
                        $state.go('app.dashboard');
                    }, function(fail){
                        // Fail get profile info
                        console.log('profile info fail', fail);
                    });
                }else{
                    $state.go('app.dashboard');
                }
      } else {
        // If (success.status === 'not_authorized') the user is logged in to Facebook,
                // but has not authenticated your app
        // Else the person is not logged into Facebook,
                // so we're not sure if they are logged into this app or not.

                console.log('getLoginStatus', success.status);

                $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Logging in...'
        });

                // Ask the permissions you need. You can learn more about
                // FB permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email', 'public_profile'], fbLoginSuccess, fbLoginError);
      }
    });
  };
})
```

My service.js code (local storage)

angular.module('Challenger.services', [])

```
.service('UserService', function() {
  // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on ionic local storage but you should save it on a database
  var setUser = function(user_data) {
    window.localStorage.starter_facebook_user = JSON.stringify(user_data);
  };

  var getUser = function(){
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.starter_facebook_user || '{}');
  };

  return {
    getUser: getUser,
    setUser: setUser
  };
});
```

Comment: Not at all. because both frameworks are frontend frameworks and running on the client. I nevered heard of a javascript mysql driver that is suitable in frontend, possible for nodejs there is one.What you need is a backend application which handels that for you!

Comment: @Rene M, yeah i maybe should of mentioned that I have a backend already setup (which is code with bootstrap, html, css, js php and mysql). the json endpoints i also already have.

Comment: Perfect that's your way

Comment: @ReneM. yeah but my question is how/where to implement it in my code

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is to simply use a JSON ajax PUT or POST from JavaScript. For example, assuming a backend host of *example.com*

Add a [CSP](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) to the Ionic HTML such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src http://example.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Add the domain to the [whitelist](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html) in the Cordova config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://example.com" />
```

Then you can call PHP from JavaScript with ajax in your angular controller (I used jQuery here but you can use any JavaScript ajax library):

```
var data = {
        authResponse: authResponse,
                userID: profileInfo.id,
                name: profileInfo.name,
                email: profileInfo.email,
        picture : "http://graph.facebook.com/" + authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
      };

$.post( "http://example.com/login.php", data, function(returnData, status) {
   console.log('PHP returned HTTP status code', status);
});
```

Finally, on the PHP side — e.g. login.php — access the post data with `$_POST['userId']`, `$_POST['email']`, etc.

Comment: mmm i am trying to follow along with your explanation but getting errors. https://gyazo.com/aaa1044216b82a8bd251dda3821e2241

Comment: It appears you are getting errors because not all external domains used by the app such as font awesome and facebook have been allowed — see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256348/content-security-policy-error-but-meta-tag-includes-url and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766985/http-equiv-content-security-policy-works-in-browser-but-not-on-android-device/38771277

Comment: Looking at the [tutorial](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework), I would replace all `UserService.setUser()` and `UserService.getUser()` statements which use browser localStorage with ajax calls to PHP/MySQL

Comment: is it possible to make a plunker?

Comment: If you put together an example on plunker, I'll definitely take a look

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have all your codes ready, but just not sure where is the best place to locate your codes. There is nice linker where has clear instruction about how to layout your php project structure: http://davidshariff.com/blog/php-project-structure/, hope this can give a kind of help.