# http-equiv Content-Security-Policy works in browser but not on android device - IONIC

Tags: android, cordova, security, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app with ionic and just inserted this Content-Security-Policy meta-tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' code.jquery.com cdn.firebase.com  www.gstatic.com maps.googleapis.com localhost:35729 apis.google.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://domain.com">
```

I don't get any errors in the browser but alot on the android device. 
I'm using crosswalk.

No errors in chrome locally but when i inspect the app with chrome://inspect and run it on the device I get these errors:

So the Content-Security-Policy isn't working on the device at all.

[image]

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you need an explicit URI scheme as described here:

[content security policy error, but meta-tag includes URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256348/content-security-policy-error-but-meta-tag-includes-url)

Thus, something like this should work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com https://cdn.firebase.com  https://www.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com localhost:35729 https://apis.google.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://domain.com">
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! You saved my day =)